# How to change plan when deploing the app?

Tags: azure, deployment, devops

I had created my own subscription for Azure App Service. Then I had deployed my app (used CLI)
After that I remove the app, the resource group as well as subscription itself.
Now I got corporate subscription, create App Service via Azure UI and now trying to deploy my app to there.

When I use command

```
az webapp up --name MyAppName
```

i get message: The webapp 'MyAppName' exists in ResourceGroup 'MyCorporateGroup' and does not match the value entered 'MyPrivategroup '. Please re-run command with the correct parameters.

When I use command:

```
az webapp up --name MyAppName --resource-group MyCorporateGroup --subscription MyCorporateSubscription
```

I get: The plan name entered 'MyCorporateGroup_0' does not match the plan name that the webapp is hosted in 'MyCorporatePlanForAppService'.Please check if you have configured defaults for plan name and re-run command.

And when I use command:

```
az webapp up --name MyAppName --resource-group MyCorporateGroup --subscription MyCorporateSubscription -p MyCorporatePlanForAppService
```

i get message: Creating AppServicePlan MyCorporatePlanForAppService ...
(InvalidResourceLocation) The resource 'MyCorporatePlanForAppService' already exists in location 'germanywestcentral' in resource group 'MyCorporateGroup'. A resource with the same name cannot be created in location 'centralus'. Please select a new resource name.

Does anyone know how can i deploy my app to the corporate app service?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem has been resolved when I remove .AZURE folder from my local machine. And then rebuild the app.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you're not changing from one context to another. Try executing the following command before trying to update the web app in your corporate subscription:

```
az account set -s <corporate-subscription-name-or-id>
```